# Jersey REST-API returns a HTTP Error 500 (but only client-side)

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I am currently working on a REST-API. I am using Jersey for that.
I programmed a couple of interfaces before, and they all worked fine. Now, I'm doing it exactly the same way (in my opinion), but it somehow won't work.

The Problem is that userGet() does not log any error (the error does not occur inside the TRY-CATCH), and it SEEMS like the method is executed successfully. But the client receives only "500 Internal Server Error"-responses.

Do you have any idea how to find out where the error occures? Or do you already know what I've done wrong?

This is my class which should be returned by the API:

```
package myproject.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserModel {

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private long id = -1;

    @XmlElement(name = "strUsername")
    private String username = null;

    @XmlTransient
    private String encryptedPassword = null;

    @XmlElement(name = "Consultant", nillable = true)
    private Consultant consultant = null;

    public UserModel(long id, String username, String encPw, Consultant co) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.encryptedPassword = encPw;
        this.consultant = co;
    }

    public static UserModel fromUser(User u) {
        return new UserModel(u.getId(), u.getName(), u.getEncryptedPassword(), u.getConsultant());
    }

    public User toUser() {
        return User.fromUserModel(this);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getEncryptedPassword() {
        return encryptedPassword;
    }

    public Consultant getConsultant() {
        return consultant;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "id=" + id + ";username=" + username + ";encPw=" + encryptedPassword;
    }
}
```

My REST-API:

```
package myproject.rest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import myproject.User;
import myproject.UserModel;
import myproject.DBUtil;
import myproject.SecurityUtil;

@Path("/app/user")
public class HandlerUser extends RestEndpoint {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HandlerUser.class);

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response userGet() {
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            con = DBUtil.getDBConnection();

            //SecurityUtil.checkRight(request);

            log.info("Collect all Users");

            List<UserModel> usermodels = new ArrayList<UserModel>();

            Iterator<User> it = User.getAll(con).iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()) {
                usermodels.add(it.next().toUserModel());
            }

            GenericEntity<List<UserModel>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<UserModel>>(usermodels) {};

            return Response.ok().entity(entity).build();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("An error occured: " + e.toString());

            return Response.status(401).entity(e.toString()).build();
        }
        finally {
            DBUtil.close(null, null, con);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** User.toUserModel() converts a User-Object to a UserModel-Object (which works fine)

Comment: Presumably you're running this REST service in some container, which one?  Are you seeing anything in the logs?

Comment: I am running it on Tomcat. The only logfile I found is localhost_access_log.SOME-DATE.txt, and there are only entries like `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [28/Apr/2014:15:04:40 +0200] "GET /MYAPP/app/user/ HTTP/1.1" 500 1063`

Comment: The server could be responding with a 500 because a provider that runs before your resource is invoked throws an exception or if Jersey itself throws an exception because it is not configured properly.  
  
In these cases you should be able to get a stack trace to appear by configuring log4j to have a console appender logging at ERROR priority in your root log configuration.

Comment: I'm getting something similar, now.  Everything was running fine, and all of sudden it's not.  One thing I did change, which did result in a successful endpoint execution, was to remove `nonPreemtive()` from my client auth config.  You can see my recent question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75463668/jersey-client-pre-flight-401s-on-basic-auth-get-request).  Of course, that fixes the auth issue, and the endpoint runs and return from the method with a status 200 and requested data, but the client still sees a status of 500.  I'm still searching for a solution to this little problem.